# Create search refiner for list name in SharePoint 2013

Tags: search-results

How could I create a search refiner for list name in SharePoint 2013? I think I can create a search refiner for list ID but how could I show list name base on list id to users in refinement webpart?

I wonder why listId and SiteTitle are managed properties but list name is not? How could I create a managed property for ListName? If I had ListName managed property could I create a search refiner for it?